# Can I just add libraries manually when visual studio 2015 installs them very slowly?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, bower, dependency-management

I am very new to visual studio. I have been using bower.json to install libraries such as bootstrap and jquery into my project, but sometimes VS takes just too long time to install one single package. Can I just add it manually out of visual studio?

I am not sure if there are any harmful issues may occur if I do that.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to allow visual studio to manage add-ins via nuget. via nuget it will manage updates and dependancies as well. 
That said, you can manually add it, but then nuget will not manage the dependancies and updates for you.

Comment: I am not sure which is better but I am currently using bower. Any benefits for using nuget over bower?

Comment: Perhaps fork the project, and see if nuget works faster? I've never worked with the others. I've always liked Nuget, so cannot really comment over which is better.